# What parameters can be passed to Airflow @task decorator?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am using Airflow 2.4.0.

```
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow import DAG

with DAG(
        "hello_world",
        start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
        schedule_interval="@daily",
        catchup=False,
) as dag:
    @task()
    def get_name():
        return {
            'first_name': 'Hongbo',
            'last_name': 'Miao',
        }

    get_name()
```

Currently I am using `@task()`. Based on the document https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html, it seems I can also use

```
@task(multiple_outputs=True)
@task(retries=3)
@task(task_id="get_name")
```

However, it does not include the explanation.

When I use `multiple_outputs=True` or `multiple_outputs=False`, or not it, the task still runs well. So I am wondering what is the purposes of it.

Is there a document listing all parameters for `@task` decorator that I can use and their actual functions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the `multiple_outputs` optional argument declared in the [task_decoratory_factory](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.4.0/airflow/decorators/base.py#L546-L557), every other option passed is forwarded to the underlying Airflow Operator.

When using `task` decorator as-is like

```
@task
def fn(): pass
```

the [default operator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.4.0/airflow/decorators/base.py#L546-L557) is the [PythonOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.4.0/airflow/decorators/base.py#L546-L557).

You can explore the mandatory/optional parameters for the Airflow Operator encapsulated by the decorator to have a better idea of the signature for the specific task.